# Show Google Static map with route in android

Tags: android

I am able to show marker on Google static map but I want to use Google static map with route between two points may any one tell how can  i display route on Google static map b/w points
In this code the first url is running ok but when i use path url it not working it gives me url error pls any one help me for path in static url 
This is my code :

```
package com.example.staticmap;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ImageView image;
        @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        image= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
   new abc().execute();
 //  image.setImageBitmap(bmp);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }


    class abc extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap>{
        double lati = 29.39444;
        double longi= 76.966041;

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Bitmap bmp = null;
        try{
String URL = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=&markers=color:blue%7Clabel:S%7C" +lati + "," + longi + "&zoom=15&size=200x200&maptype=roadmap&sensor=false";    

       //String URL = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=400x400&path=40.737102,-73.990318|40.749825,-73.987963|40.752946,-73.987384|40.755823,-73.986397&sensor=false";

       // bmp = null;
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();   
                HttpGet request = new HttpGet(URL); 

                InputStream in = null;
                try {
                    in = httpclient.execute(request).getEntity().getContent();
                    bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);

                    in.close();

                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

        }catch(Exception ee){
            ee.printStackTrace();
        }

            return bmp;
        }

    @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
            image.setImageBitmap(result);
        }

    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Following code helps you display route in built-in MAP:

```
String fullAddress = "Your full address";

//Using address
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&daddr=" + fullAddress));

//Using Latitude,Longitude
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&daddr=51.448,-0.972"));

intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity"));

startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Hi Pratik thanks for this response but i donot want to open browser i want to show in fregment and also want to show a list of route in fregment may you tell me

Comment: You can parse that URI in `WebView`

Answer (score -1):

You can use screenshot of map with route between two geopoints in image view.,here is a good example of drawing a route between to geopoints
http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/drawing-driving-route-directions-between-two-locations-using-google-directions-in-google-map-android-api-v2/